# How to draw shapes with CustomPainter and how the values of each functions work? (aka cubicto beziers quadraticbezier etc)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to draw orange and semitransparent orange curves using CustomPainter. How can I draw this?
[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8bzN.png)

[what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a30FG.png)

my code

```
var sw = size.width;
    var sh = size.height;
    var paint = Paint();

    Path mainGround = Path();
    mainGround.addRect(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, sw, sh));
    paint.color = Colors.grey[100];
    canvas.drawPath(mainGround, paint);

    Path orangeWave = Path();
    orangeWave.lineTo(sw, 0);
    orangeWave.cubicTo(
      sw * 0.3,
      sh * 0.15,
      sw * 0.2,
      sh * -0.01,
      0,
      sh * 0.15,
    );
    orangeWave.close();
    paint.color = Colors.orange[700];
    canvas.drawPath(orangeWave, paint);

    Path fadeWave1 = Path();
    fadeWave1.lineTo(sw * 0.7, 0);
    fadeWave1.cubicTo(
        sw * 0.6, sh * 0.05, sw * 0.27, sh * 0.01, sw * 0.18, sh * 0.12);
    fadeWave1.quadraticBezierTo(sw * 0.12, sh * 0.2, 0, sh * 0.2);
    fadeWave1.close();
    paint.color = Colors.orange[700].withOpacity(0.3);
    canvas.drawPath(fadeWave1, paint);
```

I can't seem to understand how they get their starting point and ending point with only one values in 2D canvas(x,y) and overall effects of the cubicTo and quadraticBezierTo

Comment: https://fluttershapemaker.com/ try this if you want to make custom shapes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Path.lineTo`, `Path.cubicTo` etc. draw a line/curve curve from the "current point". The "current point" will initially be `(0, 0)` and is changed to the end position of `lineTo` (and friends). To move the "current point" without drawing something between the previous and new location, you can use `Path.moveTo`.

For example, to draw a triangle somewhere in the middle of a canvas:

```dart
final triangle = Path()
  ..moveTo(10, 20)  // move to the starting point
  ..lineTo(30, 20)  // draw the first edge
  ..lineTo(50, 30)  // draw the second edge
  ..lineTo(10, 20);  // back to the start, drawing the third edge
```

Comment: Oh! now I get how the current point changes positions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use this package, [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers), WaveClipperTwo is similar to what you want, you can put two WaveClipperTwo with different height in Stack:

```
ClipPath(
            clipper: WaveClipperTwo(flip: true, reverse: true),
            child: Container(
              height: 120,
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: Container(),
            ),
          ),
```

OR

Follow this article, [clipping-widgets-with-bezier-curves-in-flutter](https://iiro.dev/2017/09/04/clipping-widgets-with-bezier-curves-in-flutter/), it teaches how to draw custom curves quite detail:

```
class WavyHeaderImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      child: Image.asset('images/coffee_header.jpeg'),
      clipper: BottomWaveClipper(),
    );
  }
}

class BottomWaveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 20);

    var firstControlPoint = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height);
    var firstEndPoint = Offset(size.width / 2.25, size.height - 30.0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy,
        firstEndPoint.dx, firstEndPoint.dy);

    var secondControlPoint =
        Offset(size.width - (size.width / 3.25), size.height - 65);
    var secondEndPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height - 40);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(secondControlPoint.dx, secondControlPoint.dy,
        secondEndPoint.dx, secondEndPoint.dy);

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 40);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: simple and interesting approach, though I don't think this lets me have much freedom to what curves and shapes I'd like to draw.

Comment: I've updated new example which is using CustomClipper, similar to what you want